# Update app (Android) on Google play with new project?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I had to start a new project because of some problems that I had with my old one. I already published the old one, is there anyway I can make modifications to the new one so that I can just update my new project's apk into the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the project name as same as the earlier one. Sign your new project's apk with the existing `keystore` you used for the preceding apk. Log in to your `developer console`, choose the app --- APK --- `Upload new APK to Production
[image]

Comment: If it really helped you, please up-vote the answer. I hope an up-vote won't hurt you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you upload a new apk to the play store with the same package name as the previous one, every user using the previous apk will be able to see that an update is available for the app and he may or may not update it depending on his preferences.